# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createClient') in react + contentful

Tags: reactjs, undefined, contentful, contentful-api

In my node project contentful is running same lines with my react project. But in react gives me an error, in the image below. I tried to reinstall again but it doesn't work. Did I miss something? Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I have the same issue here and tried many versions including yours and the one that I have working on other projects (the destructured one proposed as an answer) and nothing works. In my case I use SvelteKit instead of React.

Answer (score 4):

import { createClient } from "contentful";

const contentfulClient = createClien({
"your code"
});